# Regex matches from command line, doesn't match from bash script

Tags: regex, bash

I'm a bit confused: how come a regular expression works perfectly well using grep from command line and as I use the exactly same regular expression in a bash conditional statement, it doesn't work at all?

I'd like to match all the strings containing letters only, therefore my regular expression is:
`^[a-zA-Z]\+$`.

Please will you help sort this out?

Here's the snippet from my bash code

```
if ! [[ "$1" =~ '^[a-zA-z]+$' ]] ; then
    echo "Error: illegal input string." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't escape the `+`.

This works for me:

```
$ [[ "Abc" =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+$ ]] && echo "it matches"
$ it matches
```

Also, you don't need single quotes around the regex. The following works for me:

```
if ! [[ "$1" =~ ^[a-zA-z]+$ ]] ; then
    echo "Error: illegal input string." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Here's a snippet from my program

`if ! [[ "$1" =~ '^[a-zA-z]+$' ]] ; then
 echo "Error: illegal input string." >&2
 exit 1
fi`

Comment: Remove the single quotes around the regex.

Comment: which version of bash are you using? does my snippet work for you?

Comment: Yes, i've tested it, your snippet works just fine. GNU bash, version 4.2.24.

Comment: your code works for me (after removing the single quotes around the regex).

Comment: do we have the same bash version?

Comment: yes, we have the same version. If my first snippet works, then there is no reason why the second one shouldn't.

Comment: I agree with you and yet shell interpreter begs to differ. That is why I'm losing my mind.

Comment: @haunted85: When you quote the regex, it becomes a literal string instead. You should usually put the regex in a variable since that solves some of the problems that may tempt you to use quotes (you can/should use quotes for the variable assignment, though): `patt='^[a-zA-z]+$'; if ! [[ $1 =~ $patt ]]`. By the way, you haven't said precisely how dogbane's or your snippets fail.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: when I used my or dogbane's snippet my script didn't seem to match any string and I got back `"Error: illegal input string."` at every input. I tried to assign my pattern to a variable and perform the check the way you suggest but the issue is still there.